# Recursively print struct in `fmt::Display`

Tags: struct, console, rust, println

I'm currently in the process of implementing `fmt::Display` for a struct so that it will print out to the console. However The struct has a field which is a `Vec` of it's type.

### Struct

```
pub struct Node<'a> {
    pub start_tag: &'a str,
    pub end_tag: &'a str,
    pub content: String,
    pub children: Vec<Node<'a>>,
}
```

### Current fmt::Display (invalid)

```
impl<'a> fmt::Display for Node<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "START TAG: {:?}", self.start_tag);
        write!(f, "CONTENT: {:?}", self.content);
        for node in self.children {
            write!(f, "CHILDREN:\n\t {:?}", node);
        }
        write!(f, "END TAG: {:?}", self.end_tag);
    }
}
```

### Desired Output

```
START TAG: "Hello"
CONTENT: ""
CHILDREN:
   PRINTS CHILDREN WITH INDENT
END TAG: "World"
```

Comment: `for node in self.children` → `for node in &self.children`. Also use `try!()` around each `write`. (welcome to format this into an answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a (somewhat hidden) feature of `Debug`, you can use the format specifier `{:#?}` to pretty-print your object (with indents and multiple lines). If you rewrite your struct's elements to have the same order as your requested output and derive the `Debug` trait

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<'a> {
    pub start_tag: &'a str,
    pub content: String,
    pub children: Vec<Node<'a>>,
    pub end_tag: &'a str,
}
```

then your output can look like this:

```
Node {
    start_tag: "Hello",
    content: "",
    children: [
        Node {
            start_tag: "Foo",
            content: "",
            children: [],
            end_tag: "Bar"
        }
    ],
    end_tag: "World"
}
```

Try it out in the [PlayPen](http://is.gd/36avQN)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are confusing [`Display`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) and [`Debug`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html).

`{:?}` uses the `Debug` trait for formatting. You probably didn't implement `Debug` on your type, which is why you'd get an error. To use the `Display` trait, write `{}` in your format string.

```
write!(f, "CHILDREN:\n\t {}", node);
```

Comment: Semantically this sort of output is far more likely to be suitable for `Debug` than `Display`, incidentally.